# How to access my user mode thread_local variables inside my windows kernel driver?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver

I want to create a shared memory for communication between my .exe and my driver.
My current plan is to have thread_local variables in the usermode and then use them for communication.

.exe

```
typedef struct blabla {
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
int c = 30;
int d = 40;

}blabla, * pblabla;

volatile thread_local blabla dd;
```

.driver

```
PEPROCESS process = FunctionToGetProcess();
auto next_entry = process->ThreadListHead.Flink;

while (next_entry != &process->ThreadListHead)
{
    PETHREAD thread = (PETHREAD)CONTAINING_RECORD(next_entry, _KTHREAD, ThreadListEntry);

    
    auto teb = (PTEB)thread->Teb;

    
    for (int i = 0; i <= 63; ++i) {
        if (teb->TlsSlots[i] != NULL) {
            Log("Values :  %d \n", test);
        }
        else {
            Log("NULL\n");
        }
    }
    
    
    next_entry = next_entry->Flink;


}
```

TEB MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-teb

Thread Local Storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-local-storage

The Documentation doesn't provide enough information for me to know how to access them. I currently find my EPROCESS and then iterate through all ETHREAD's -> TEB-> TLS.

I am aware that The offset of the fields for the WIN STRUCTURES are unofficial and will be (possibly) different across OS-es and
service pack,
and they may disappear in future version. Since i will always only use the same OS Version
without updating it it is no problem. Im also aware that there are WINAPI calls for creating shared memory and that the basic
communication is IOCTL. My Goal is to do it without the use of WINAPI calls inside user mode land.